# Changing the text colour of Facebook Comment Box Plugin

Tags: facebook, comments

I am using the facebook comment plugin on my site.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments  style="background-color:#131514;" href="http://kablammo.com.au/news_article.php?&amp;newsID='.$i.'" num_posts="3"  width="500"  ></fb:comments>
```

I saw in a post that you could effect the backgound colour by putting in:

```
style="background-color:#131514;"
```

However to get it to work you have to remove the colourscheme `colorscheme="dark"` and in doing so the comment text returns to black.

How can I change the comment text colour?

I tried putting in `color:#FFF` but no such luck.

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an external stylesheet and reference that in your `<fb:comments>` call.

Eg: `<fb:comments numposts="4" title="My Blog Comments" css="http://www.yourwebsite.com/css/comments.css?1234" simple="1"></fb:comments>`

Please read the following for reference:

- Official Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)/
- Tutorial on how to target elements in the Facebook comment box: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin-on-a-static-fbml-tab/